# Flutter drop down arrow position

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am able to show the dropdown properly but the issue is the arrow comes at the end and ass the dropdown contains some small and some big word the arrow adjust according to the big words.
I tried to hide the arrow and show a dummy arrow in a row with the text but that will also be visible in the dropdown [image: the dropdown arrow] how to show the arrow with the text end

Comment: I think you can wrap the dropdown or the texts inside a Container with a fixed width, and then it will be constant through out all text.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

1. In your `DropdownButton` use this property `isExpanded: true,`

Like this :

```
 DrowpdownButton(
   //other attributes..
   isExpanded: true,
 )
```

2. If this doesn't work, wrap your `DropdownButton` in a `Row` and use `Expanded`

Like this :

This may produce error, based on your code, or widgets arranged

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max
  children:[
    Expanded(
      flex:1.
      child: DrowdownButton(
             //Other attr
             isExpanded: true,
           )
       )
   ]
)
```

Try 1st one first, then second one.